# Haskell maybe function bewilderment

Tags: haskell

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b  -- Defined in `Data.Maybe'
```

From this definition of maybe, b can be any type and should be the same type as the return value of the function (a-> b)
But when i tried this in Winghci:

```
maybe (error "no") (head) (Just "hi")
'h'
maybe (error "no") (return) (Just "hi")
"hi"
```

Both works but clearly return and head has different types and yet both work with (error "no")
When I type:

```
:t error "no"
```

I get

```
error "no" :: a
```

Does this mean error "no" can be any type ?
Why so ?

Comment: Yes, `error "..."`, like `undefined`, can have any type.  An intuition is that whatever is evaluating it will never get a chance to see it (because the whole computation aborts), so it never has a chance to be the wrong type.

Comment: Yes, `error "no"` can be any type. That's the point of `error`. `error :: String -> a`, for a sort of unrecoverable failure. How did you come to be using `error` in the first place?

Comment: @shachaf Do you mean this is not typically how people use maybe or error ? I've seen this code somewhere else in a Haskell tutorial

Comment: You can use it when you know that the `Maybe a` value will never be `Nothing`, and you want to crash your program with an informative error if you ever happen to be wrong. You certainly shouldn't do that by default -- it sort of defeats the point of `Maybe` (though it does at least it forces you to consider the `Nothing` case in the right place).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> :t error
error :: [Char] -> a
```

`error` takes a `String` so you can inform the user what problem was.

As it returning `a`, it's because errors can happen anywhere in a program, so if it is "any type" you can set an error anywhere you need to.

For example:

the function `head` has the signature

```
head :: [a] -> a
```

it obviously returns the head of a list.

but what happens if we give to it an **empty** list.

```
Prelude> head ([] :: [Int])
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

`head` was supposed to return a type `Int` because we forced it in the empty list

```
Prelude> :t head ([] :: [Int])
head ([] :: [Int]) :: Int
```

So what can we return that is type `Int` (for this particular case) and shows the user that something went wrong?

```
error "empty list"
```

but we need it to be `Int`, so error, as being `a`, can be anything, such as `Int`

The source code for `head` is like this:

```
head :: [a] -> a
head (x:_) = x
head []    = error "empty list"
```